# Delphi - floodfill with gradient?

Tags: delphi, gdi, gradient, flood-fill

Is there a way to use Canvas.FloodFill in D2007 to fill a custom shaped object with gradient colors. Going from white to a border color.
I couldn't google out anything useful.

Or just any other way of filling a custom shaped object with gradient colors?

Thank you.

Comment: you need to create or google for a method that generates gradient, make sure you get the one which uses scan line, it's faster

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.

Floodfill takes uses whatever the current brush color is set to, you can't change it during the flood fill.

You could however use floodfill to set the color to something not already in the image, then loop over the pixels, check for that color of the pixel, and do a gradient fill that way. That would take care of the boundary detection for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked GDI+ already? You can make Shapes (Pathes) and gradient-fill them with GDI+. There are some Delphi-Wrappers around for GDI+ with examples:

Here is a starting point:

http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus/index.shtml

Comment: this is D2009 as I see on the website. I'm using 2007. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There are other implementations as well, also for "older" Delphis. For example: http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=7 GDI+ is quite easy to use!